# Why does my enumerated type code return "object has no attribute"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and having trouble with this code.

```
class Enum:
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.mydict = dict()
        i = 1
        for element in y:
            self.mydict.update({element: i})
            i += 1
        self.myreversedict = dict(zip(list(self.mydict.keys()), list(self.mydict.values())))

    def cast(self, y):
        return self.mydict[y]

temp = Enum(['Left','Right'])
temp.cast(1)
```

The error I received is `'Enum' object has no attribute 'Left'`.

I'm trying to enumerate a data set without using the enumerated built-in function (e.g. `{'Left':1, 'Right': 2}` ). Calling a method, that inputs an integer, should be able to output the corresponding string (in the above code, `temp.cast(1)` should return `'Right'`).

Comment: On which line did you receive the error?

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Comment: Line 15 : AttributeError: 'Enum' object has no attribute 'Left'

Comment: When I ran your code the error I got was a `KeyError` when calling `temp.cast(1)` because you are trying to access the key `1` when your dict only has the keys 'Right' and 'Left'. Your `myreversedict` is also just an exact copy of `mydict`

Comment: as an aside, don't do this: `self.mydict.update({element: i})`, just do `self.mydict[element] = i`

Comment: I think you meant to reverse value and key in self.myreversedict like self.myreversedict = dict(zip(list(self.mydict.values()), list(self.mydict.keys()))) and return self.myreversedict[y]

Comment: The error raises in line 15, but you just show us 14 lines ... I assume you do sth. along the lines of `temp.Left` there. That cannot work, because the elements of your input list never become attributes of the `Enum` instance. Also, why should `temp.cast(1)` return `Right` in your example code? Looks very much like it should return `Left` to me. `temp.cast(2)` should be `Right`, no?

Comment: @shmee would using the `setattr` function make the input attributes of the `Enum` instance?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Which also means you just need one dict to hold the reverse assignment of value to key.